# No reply produced by Handler xxxx and its 'requiresReply' property is set to true

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, scatter-plot

In Scatter Gather pattern, especially in Distribution variant, i am trying to use "correlation-strategy-expression" in gatherer element by passing header attribute as below, i am getting "No reply produced by handler xxxx and its "requireReply" property is set to true. Below is config

```
<scatter-gather input-channel="inputDistribution" output-channel="output" gather-channel="gatherChannel">
    <scatterer>
        <recipient channel="distribution1Channel"/>
        <recipient channel="distribution2Channel"/>
        <recipient channel="distribution3Channel"/>
    </scatterer>
    <gatherer correlation-strategy-expression="headers[CorrelationId]'/>
</scatter-gather>
```

where in test code i am explicitly setting header attribute as below
MessageBuilder.writhPayload("foo").setHeader(MessageHeaders.REPLY_CHANEL,output).setHeader("CorrelationId","foo").build().

Note:It is working fine if i use apply-sequene=true as scatterer attribute.

can you please suggest what is wrong in configuration, do we need any bean to define?

Tried using correlation-strategry-expression but getting error

Comment: We don't know what you are doing with this code. But probably when you create a reply message you lose request message headers, where that `gather-channel` value is set as a `.setReplyChannel(this.gatherChannel)`. I don't think that correlation expression is relevant to your problem.

Comment: Hi @ArtemBilan, i am trying to run Distribution variant example using custom correlation strategy where using expression to correlate request messages.

Comment: without expression getting below error
'org.springframework.integration.scattergather.ScatterGatherHandler#0.gatherer'; xxxx/scatter-gather-context.xml]'; from source: ''gatherer'']; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Null correlation not allowed.  Maybe the CorrelationStrategy is failing?, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=5.677678895858088, headers={replyChannel=bean 'gatherChannel', gatherResultChannel=org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannelxx CorrelationId=foo, id=xxx, timestamp=xx}]

Comment: This is not related. Of course, if no `apply-sequene=true` and no `correlation-strategry-expression` we get an error you describe. With your original problem you just lose a `replyChannel` header in the reply message you produce back from one of those distribution channels. See if you can build that `foo` based on headers from request message.

Comment: Below is remaining configuration
 <bridge input-channel="distribution1Channel" output-channel="serviceChannel1"/>
<bridge input-channel="distribution2Channel" output-channel="serviceChannel1"/>
    <bridge input-channel="distribution3Channel" output-channel="serviceChannel1"/>
 <service-activator input-channel="serviceChannel1" output-channel="gatherChannel"
                       expression="T(java.lang.Math).random() * 10"/>

Comment: This code is not readable. Please, respect our vision and add the code properly formatted into your question editing it. I believe this issue is yours: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/issues/338

Comment: Looks like you took some code from the https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/main/spring-integration-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/scattergather/config/ScatterGatherTests.java and its configuration. We don't do that `MessageBuilder.writhPayload("foo").setHeader(MessageHeaders.REPLY_CHANEL,output)` anywhere in that test code.

Comment: Might be great if you share with us a code of the test class and its configuration to see the whole context of what you are really modifying for that `ScatterGatherTests`

Comment: It also might be helpful for us to see the whole stacktrace of the error you got. I guess now it is pointless to hide your handler behind that `xxx` since we have just determined that you have borrowed the code from the `ScatterGatherTests`

Comment: The `"headers[CorrelationId]'` is wrong definition. Must be double quote on both side. This your code is just not compilable.

Comment: `withPayload()`, not `writhPayload`. Too many mistakes even in this SO question...

Comment: Just modified our `<scatter-gather input-channel="inputDistribution"` with a `correlation-strategy-expression="headers[CorrelationId]"` and then that `public void testDistribution() {` with this code: `this.inputDistribution.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo").setHeader("CorrelationId", "foo").build());` - and test still passes OK.

Comment: Thank you @ArtemBilan for your response, sorry i removed/replace with xxx because of char limit in comment... Yes it is from sample application provide in spring-integration.

Comment: Just noticed that apply-sequence is true by default starting with version 6.0 and i am running application using "implementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:5.5.15'"  and i am looking for custom correlation strategy implemented using expression.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your concern still unclear. I believe that you just don't show us all the relevant code which causes that error.

Here is a config:

```
<channel id="output">
    <queue/>
</channel>

<!--Distribution scenario-->
<scatter-gather input-channel="inputDistribution" output-channel="output" gather-channel="gatherChannel">
    <scatterer>
        <recipient channel="distribution1Channel"/>
        <recipient channel="distribution2Channel"/>
        <recipient channel="distribution3Channel"/>
    </scatterer>
    <gatherer release-strategy-expression="messages.^[payload gt 5] != null or size() == 3"
              correlation-strategy-expression="headers[CorrelationId]"/>
</scatter-gather>

<channel id="gatherChannel">
    <queue/>
</channel>

<bridge input-channel="distribution1Channel" output-channel="serviceChannel2"/>

<bridge input-channel="distribution2Channel" output-channel="serviceChannel2"/>

<bridge input-channel="distribution3Channel" output-channel="serviceChannel2"/>

<service-activator input-channel="serviceChannel2" output-channel="gatherChannel"
                   expression="T(java.lang.Math).random() * 10"/>
```

and here is a code of unit test:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext
public class ScatterGatherTests {

    @Autowired
    private PollableChannel output;

    @Autowired
    private MessageChannel inputDistribution;

    @Test
    public void testDistribution() {
        this.inputDistribution.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo").setHeader("CorrelationId", "foo").build());
        Message<?> bestQuoteMessage = this.output.receive(10000);
        assertThat(bestQuoteMessage)
                .isNotNull()
                .extracting(Message::getPayload)
                .isInstanceOf(List.class)
                .asList()
                .hasSizeGreaterThanOrEqualTo(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @Artem .. after adding release strategy it is working fine